# Read and write matrix

Tags: c, loops, pointers

i have written this code to take input of r*c matrix

r -> rows
c -> columns

it works fine when r<=c
but fails to produce correct output when r>c.

Example:

r=6, c=2

input:
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
11 12

output:

1 2
11 12
5 6
11 12
11 12
11 12

please tell me where i am going wrong.
i don't want to use constant size array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void scanmatrix(int* a[],int r,int c)
{
int i,j;

for(i=0;i<r;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
}
}

void printmatrix(int* a[],int r,int c)
{
int i,j;

for(i=0;i<r;i++)
{
    printf("\n\n");
    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
    }
}
}

int main()
{
int* a;

int r,c,i,j;

scanf("%d%d",&r,&c);

a=(int *)malloc(r*c*sizeof(int));

scanmatrix(&a,r,c);
printmatrix(&a,r,c);

return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using single pointer to allocate 2d dimesional array means allocating memory continously.so you cant use subscript like a[i][j], for that you need to point pointer correctly

Below code shows how u can use single pointer to store 2D array the same thing u can implement in your code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define COL 2
#define ROW 6
int main()
{
        int *p,i,j;
        p=(int *)malloc(ROW*COL*sizeof(int ));
         for(i=0;i<ROW;i++)
        {
                for(j=0;j<COL;j++)
                {
                        scanf("%d\t",&p[i*COL+j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }

        for(i=0;i<ROW;i++)
        {
                for(j=0;j<COL;j++)
                {
                        printf("%d\t",p[i*COL+j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you want to use to access or write element to matrix using 2 subscript as in case a[i][j] then you can use double pointer that makes easy to use like p[i][j]

Answer (score 0):

You have allocated 1-dim array, but treat it as a 2-dim array. That's asking for surprises :)

possible fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void scanmatrix(int* a,int r,int c)
{
int i,j;

for(i=0;i<r;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    {
        int k = c*i+j;
        scanf("%d",a+k);
    }
}
}

void printmatrix(int* a,int r,int c)
{
int i,j;

for(i=0;i<r;i++)
{
    printf("\n\n");
    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    {
        int k = c*i+j;
        printf("%d\t",a[k]);
    }
}
}

int main()
{
int* a;

int r,c,i,j;

scanf("%d%d",&r,&c);

a=(int *)malloc(r*c*sizeof(int));

scanmatrix(&a,r,c);
printmatrix(&a,r,c);

return(0);
}
```

Comment: The line `int k = c*(i-1)+j;` should be `int k = c*i+j;` since the index `i` starts from 0, not 1.