# how to use int ** instead of int [][] two dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, dimensional

```
typedef struct{
       int rows, cols;    // matrix dimensions
       int **element;     // element array
}Matrix;
```

If i were to create a variable:

```
Matrix m;
```

How would i go about creating a 3x3 {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}} array in the `Matrix`?
Or for that matter, how could i store any sized two-dimensional array into m.element?

I have tried:

```
for (i=0; i<m.rows; i++)
{
    for (k=0; k<m.cols; k++)
    {
        m.element=q;
        q++;
    }
}
```

Comment: reference this [Dynamic Allocation of 2D Array][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583836/dynamic-allocation-of-2d-array/17584120#17584120

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572696/read-and-write-matrix/19573110#19573110

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate space for the matrix. Simply assigning values to `m.elements[i][j]` will do attempt to access memory at unknown locations, as `m.elements` will be uninitialized and will have essentially random values.  Your program may not be able to access it, or it might not be aligned properly. Build a function to create a `rows` × `cols` matrix:

```
// Initialize and return a passed-in matrix.
// matrix must point to an allocated struct, not NULL.
void build(Matrix * const matrix, const size_t rows, const size_t cols) {
    matrix->rows = rows;
    matrix->cols = cols;
    matrix->elements = malloc(rows * sizeof(int *));
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        matrix->elements[row] = malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

Note that you can create arrays of any shape.  If you need to create symmetric matrices, you need only store items not below the main diagonal.

Since this dynamically allocates the 2-dimensional array, it's your responsibility to `free` it when you are done:

```
void destroy(Matrix * const matrix) {
    for (size_t row = 0; row < matrix->rows; row++) {
        free(matrix->elements[row]);
    }
    free(matrix->elements);
}
```

Comment: Okay, your answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the advice of the comment and look at [Dynamic Allocation of 2D Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583836/dynamic-allocation-of-2d-array/17584120#17584120)

Then do

```
for (i = 0; i < m.rows; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < m.cols; j++) {
    m.element[i][j] = q++;
  }
}
```

You need to add in the `m.element[i][j]` part to make it work.

Comment: That won't work.  `m.element` won't be initialized to anything useful.  `m.element[i]` may even cause a segmentation fault.  `m.element[i][j]` certainly will.

Comment: No; the point is that you need to allocate enough space for the array of pointers, and then for each row you need to allocate enough space for its elements. I'll answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Although, you should'nt use pointer to pointer for storing 2-D array, but you can do something like:

```
m.element = malloc(sizeof(int*)*3);
for (int j=0;j<3;++j)
{
    m.element[j] = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
}
```

Comment: A potential problem here is locality of data.  Based upon how the OP is iterating over the matrix (I don't know how performance sensitive his code is) he would be better served allocating one large memory chunk and doing the row/column math to look up each element (`matrix[y * cols + x`)

Comment: @EdS.  Good point. Didn't think of that. But then probably he would have to change his element from `**` to `*`, right?

Comment: the typedef struct cannot be changed, must be **

Comment: This is a student problem, I guess.

Comment: @runnercto: then performance doesn't matter and you can just do it this way